# Does Okabe meet Maho in the Steins;Gate world line? If he does, how?

Tags: steins-gate

In *Steins;Gate 0*, does Okabe meet Maho in the Steins;Gate world line? If he does, how?

Don't know if he does. I think it's up to our imagination, but maybe Okabe does meet Maho.

Comment: Related on Reddit: [A question about Maho.](https://www.reddit.com/r/steinsgate/comments/5no5sn/a_question_about_maho/)

Answer (score 1):

I would assume so seeing as his plan was always to continue on to a higher-up university and being together with Kurisu he most likely would have crossed paths with her sooner or later.

Although the difference of that timeline after Okabe saves Kurisu has infinitely differing events seeing as the timeline has shifted, there is no telling what might actually happen but my assumption would be the former alternative where he does meet her seeing as Maho would sooner or later meet up with Kurisu because she is Salieri just as Kurisu is Mozart.

Maho lives her life striving to become the equal of Kurisu so she would ultimately find a way to meet with her and go over Kurisu's findings while also striving to attain what she, Maho feels is attaining equal standing with Kurisu.

There is a possibility that Okabe and Kurisu don't stay together but I would hope that timeline wouldn't have to exist because of how downtrodden Okabe became in Steins;Gate 0 without Kurisu.

But to wrap this up I would say that no one could know unless they came out with a continuance for Steins;Gate because the changes could be infinite and we can never truly make time move the way we want it to.

Comment: Basically, up to our imagination.

Comment: I mean there are many signs pointing to them meeting up, but in theory yes the timeline has infinite possibilities of change and so you could sum it up to just our imagination.